# Sort Hashmap keys by numerical value descending order

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

How can I sort `HashMap` keys by their numerical value? Currently, in the natural ordering it looks like this:

```
1 10 13 2 26 29
```

I want it to look like this:

```
29 26 13 10 2 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `HashMap` cannot be sorted. If you require sorted keys, take a look at the [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). In order to get the reversed ordering you want, you would have to provide a custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
class ReversedOrdering implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
        // compare reversed
        return rhs.compareTo(lhs);
    }
}
```

**Edit** I just stumbled across [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) which does just what you want: It gives you a `Comparator` that reverses the natural ordering of objects that implement `Comparable`. This saves you the hassle of writing a comparator yourself.

Comment: I realised my key was not numerical anymore. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: @Maurice: I have added a simpler solution to get the reverse of a natural ordering (the type of the keys does not matter: if the implement `Comparable`, you can reverse the ordering this way).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and then call [descendingMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap()) on it which basically returns a map with the reverse ordering of the keys

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` doesn't sort anything. Use a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead if you want to keep the keys sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with the constructor that lets you specify a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it works fine and based on order flag it will sort ascending or descending.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 * @author Rais.Alam
 * @date Dec 12, 2012
 */
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final boolean order = true;
        try
        {

            Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(
                    new Comparator<Integer>()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(Integer first, Integer second)
                        {

                            if (order)
                            {

                                return second.compareTo(first);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return first.compareTo(second);

                            }
                        }
                    });

            map.put(2, "v");
            map.put(3, "h");
            map.put(4, "e");
            map.put(1, "a");

            System.out.println(map);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```