# How to overcome freemarker treeset sorting int keys alphabetically?

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, freemarker, treeset

I have a TreeSet.

The string key is actually a string value of an int, as freemarker doesn't allow ints as keys to maps, and as this is a sorted map, it sorts it as below:

1 
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Anyone know how to get around this and make it print in numerical order?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7227772/681807

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9556369/681807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` internally imposes a [*lexicographic order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) via [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

> Compares two strings lexicographically.

If you don't want that, consider specifying a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) e.g.

```
final Map<String, ...> map = new TreeMap<String, ...>(new Comparator<String>() {

  public int compare(final String a, final String b) {
    return Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Construct the map with an appropriate comparator via the constructor [`TreeMap(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29).

(Or TreeSet, if that's what you actually mean; you mention both sets and maps.)